# remoteEntry.js not found on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, webpack, deployment, next.js, micro-frontend

We are deploying a remote app written in NextJS and Typescript; The host app is in React only.

Currently the host app gets a 404 not found error as the remote app runs into this error in the Build Snapshot on Jenkins

```
+ ls ./dist/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js
ls: cannot access './dist/static/chunks/remoteEntry.js': No such file or directory
script returned exit code 2
```

However, the file is generated locally and both apps are able to spin up in local environment.

Here is our next.config.js:

```
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const { exposedModules } = require('./lib/routes');
const version = process.env.VERSION_OVERRIDE || require('./package.json').version;
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

// Note: This path needs to match with what's specified in CIRRUS_FRONTEND_ENTRYPOINT for www.
const assetBasePath = process.env.CDN_PATH ? `${process.env.CDN_PATH}${version}` : process.env.ASSET_BASE_PATH;

// Note: Heavily references module federation example meant for omnidirectional federation between Next apps.
//       Changes mostly around path resolution due to our current resolution pattern via cdn
//       https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/nextjs/home/next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    Object.assign(config.experiments, { topLevelAwait: true });

    // Integrated mode calls `next build` which has minimization by default. For local development, this is unnecessary.
    if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT === 'INTEGRATED') {
      config.optimization.minimize = false;
    }

    if (!options.isServer) {
      console.log("Not Server");
      config.output.publicPath = 'auto';
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'cirrus',
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './FederatedRouter': './lib/FederatedRouter',
            ...exposedModules
          },
          remoteType: 'var',
          remotes: {},
          shared: {
            '@transcriptic/amino': {
              requiredVersion: deps['@transcriptic/amino'],
              singleton: true
            },
            react: {
              requiredVersion: deps.react,
              singleton: true
            },
            'react-dom': {
              requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
              singleton: true
            },
            '@strateos/micro-apps-utils': {
              requiredVersion: deps['@strateos/micro-apps-utils'],
              singleton: true
            }
          },
          extraOptions: {
            // We need to override the default module sharing behavior of this plugin as that assumes a nextjs host
            // and thus next modules will be provided by the parent application.
            // However, web is currently NOT a nextjs application so this child application so that assumption is
            // invalid. Note that this means we need to ensure we explicitly specify common modules such as `react`
            // in the `shared` key above.
            skipSharingNextInternals: true
          }
        })
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Is Server");
    }
    return config;
  },
  // Note: Annoyingly, NextJS automatically automatically appends a `_next` directory for assetPrefix
  //       but NOT public path so we'll have to manually include it here.
  publicPath: `${assetBasePath}/_next/`,
  // Note: If serving assets via CDN, assetPrefix is required to help resolve static assets.
  //       Also, NextJS automatically appends and expects a `_next` directory to the assetPrefix path.
  //       See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix
  assetPrefix: process.env.CDN_PATH ? assetBasePath : undefined,
  distDir: 'dist',
  // Use index react-router as fallback for resolving any pages that are not directly specified
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      fallback: [
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          destination: '/'
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

- Tried upgrade NextJS from 12.1.6 to 12.2.2
- Tried upgrade Webpack from 5.74.0 to 5.75.0
- Cleaned cache by `sh 'yarn cache clean'`
- Tried clear env by `sh 'env -i PATH=$PATH make build-snapshot'`
- Hash of node modules by `tar -cf - node_modules | md5sum`
- Downgraded `"@module-federation/nextjs-mf"` from 5.12.9 to 5.10.5
- Verified file writing permission

Comment: okay ... we found the issue ... the minifier NextJS has by default remove module federation files. after setting `config.optimization.minimize = false;`, the build snapshot was able to generate the `remoteEntry.js` file